Cannot insert in API from code. Strangely, the same data doesn't have any problem using Postman
I am trying to insert an object into BullHorn using its API. Besides, I am using a PUT method as documentation indicated me.
This is my code:
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(bhURL);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

var model1 = new StringContent(model, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

response = await client.PutAsync(bhURL, model1).ConfigureAwait(false);

The response is always http 400. But the strange part here is that I used the bhURL (token included as query string) and the body in Postman, and it worked perfectly.
I have checked:
var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
var model1 = new StringContent(model, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Is serializing correctly the body, and it is, but the PUT call still returns 400.
My Postman's headers configuration is really basic:

Any help please?

Please include the content, if any, of the HTTP response you get from the server. Usually an object describing the error is returned in case of a bad request.

@EnricoMassone Many thanks for helping here. The response is not really interesting. Just 400 status code and then the different values supported by the API. Like max number connection per minute, how many connection are already done,... and so on. BUT, finally found the problem. Client, a web application was storing the huge json with a typo. Fixed then. Many Thanks
